# Tinting a NSSegmentedControl... how?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

I have a `NSSegmentedControl` that must be selected before the user can pass to the next phase in a wizard. I can disable the next button forcing the user to guess that something is missing but I would like to flash the control red, something like a tint or border, to call attention, if the user press NEXT without selecting an option on the control.

I did not find a single page on google telling how to do that. Is that possible to do that in cocoa? how can I do that for one `NSSegmentedControl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a tinted segmented control in [Tembo](http://www.houdah.com/Tembo). The purpose here is not to draw attention to the control, but to have it blend-in with a colored navigation bar. Top right of the [screenshot](http://www.houdah.com/Tembo/screenshots.html).

Rather than draw a segmented control from scratch, I have the standard implementation draw into an NSImage which I then [tint](https://github.com/gloubibou/NSImage-HHTint) before drawing to to the view.

The same principle could be used to draw attention to the control. You will need to call setNeedsDisplay whenever you change the tint color

```
@interface TintedSegmentedCell : NSSegmentedCell
{
    NSMutableDictionary *_frames;
}

@end


@implementation TintedSegmentedControl

@synthesize tintColor = _tintColor;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_tintColor release], _tintColor = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

+ (Class)cellClass
{
    return [TintedSegmentedCell class];
}

@end


@implementation TintedSegmentedCell

- (void)drawSegment:(NSInteger)segment inFrame:(NSRect)frame withView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [_frames setObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:frame] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:segment]];

    [super drawSegment:segment inFrame:frame withView:controlView];
}

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)view
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[TintedSegmentedControl class]]) {
        NSColor *tintColor = [(TintedSegmentedControl*)view tintColor];

        if (tintColor != nil) {
            NSRect bounds = frame;

            bounds.origin.x = 0;
            bounds.origin.y = 0;

            NSSize size = bounds.size;
            NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];

            NSInteger segmentCount = [self segmentCount];
            NSMutableDictionary *frames = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:segmentCount];

            _frames = frames;

            [image lockFocus];
            {
                [super drawWithFrame:bounds inView:view];
            }
            [image unlockFocus];

            NSImage *tintedImage = [[image hh_imageTintedWithColor:[NSColor blackColor]] hh_imageTintedWithColor:tintColor];

            [tintedImage drawInRect:frame fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

            NSImage *overlayImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];

            [overlayImage lockFocus];
            {
                _frames = nil;

                for (NSInteger segment = 0; segment < segmentCount; segment++) {
                    NSRect frameRect = [[frames objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:segment]] rectValue];

                    [self drawSegment:segment inFrame:frameRect withView:view];
                }
            }
            [overlayImage unlockFocus];

            [overlayImage drawInRect:frame fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

            return;
        }
    }

    [super drawWithFrame:frame inView:view];
}

@end
```